# How to convert an array to an object in Javascript without using loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, types

I want to convert the following array:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

to the following object:

```
{a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'}
```

How do I do it without using loop, ofcourse?

Comment: You have to use a loop of some kind. Even built in array methods use loops

Comment: @charlietfl I am looking for something shorter, maybe spread operator?

Comment: `{...['a', 'b', 'c']}` results in `{0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}`. It can't be done without map, reduce, or similar loop

Comment: spread operator is looping on the array anyway

Comment: Pick your loop... while, for, forEach, map, reduce, reduceRight etc...no way to avoid one of them. Nothing complicated once you pick the loop you want to use

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to use the `Array.reduce()` method.

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

The `reduce()` callback method takes `accumulator` and `currentValue` parameters.

- **accumulator:** Value is remembered throughout each iteration of the method and ultimately becomes the final returned value.
- **currentValue:** The current element being processed in the `array`.

The `{}` is supplied as the last argument to `reduce()` as the initial value to start with. And with each iteration of the `Array`, we add to it ultimately creating the final `Object`.

**Example:** (ES6)

```js
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const obj = letters.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator[currentValue] = currentValue;
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

**Example:** (ES5)

```js
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var obj = letters.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue) {
  accumulator[currentValue] = currentValue;
  return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

**Reference:** [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) mozilla documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You could map objects and join to a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(v => ({ [v]: v })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Any way to do this without using map?

Comment: why not with map?

Comment: map is fine but something shorter using spread operator, maybe?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution, you can also use the newer [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with map as well.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

let obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(m => [m,m]));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `Array#reduce` to get the desired result.

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const o = a.reduce((s, a) => {
   s[a] = a;
   return s;
}, {});

console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];


var obj = arr.reduce(function(obj, value) {
     obj[value] = value;
     return obj
}, {});
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The  `object.assign()` might solve your problem.

Here is an example.

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c']; 

Object.assign( {}, array);

// {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"}
```

The new object will have same index with the array.

If you want the values of the array to be same with the key.

```
function arrayToObject( array) 
{  
    var object = array.reduce( (obj, value) => {
        obj[value] = value;
        return obj
    }, {});
    return object;
}
arrayToObject( ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: @trincot thanks for mentioning. I actually thought they were the same,

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest version :

```js
console.log( ['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((o, v) => (o[v] = v, o), {}) )
```

Answer (score 0):

const values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const objectValues = {...values} =>

```js
const values = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const objectValues = {...values}

console.log(objectValues)
```